# How was Ainz able to perceive the threat of skeletal dragon beforehand and warn Nabe?

Tags: overlord

In *Overlord* season 1 episode 9, Ainz asked Narberal to watch out above her and just like he said, a skeletal dragon appeared.

I don't think it was even explained in the light novel.

Can someone clarify how Ainz was able to perceive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly in the LN, Clementine talked about the existence of a Skeletal Dragon before it lands. Ainz then thought **Nabe** couldn't able to defeat it. That is why after some time Ainz says **Naberal Gamma**. This means she can get rid of the cover and use any spell she wants.

Comment: I'm sorry if i did not word my question properly!!  BTW, yes, I do agree with you... clementine mentioned about skeletal dragon to ainz and this prompted him to ask nabe to fight as naberal gamma so that she could use her full power

Comment: But what i wanted to actually know was this..... in light novel as well as in the anime, ainz says this to nabe " watch out, above you" , Ainz actually tells this to her even before he actually fights/speaks with clementine.... so ainz should not have known about any dragons,. but how was it that ainz was right about giving a warning to nabe??

Comment: did he use any knid of power to detect the danger, it was not explained even in light novel, i just read the chapter to find any hints, but i could not find any!!

Comment: Oh I see. Since Ainz's last class is Overlord he can detect undead. Skill name is "Undead Blessing". [Source](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Ainz_Ooal_Gown/Abilities_and_Powers)